# connect pod from k8s to google storage

Tags: java, apache-camel, google-cloud-storage

I need to connect Camel to GCP storage (bucket) with the Camel google-storage component. Camel running in k8s (GCP).

The component accepts a key file. this works locally when provided a key file.

For security reasons, I don't want to include the key file in the POD but somehow enable the POD to access GCP services.

What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workload Identity is the recommended way to access Google Cloud services from applications running within Google Kubernetes Engine. [Using Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity).

Otherwise, you can create and use a service account and assign it storage roles. And keys can be used with service accounts. [Using Service account for authentication to Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform#:%7E:text=To%20give%20your%20application%20running,permissions%20associated%20with%20your%20application.&text=To%20create%20a%20service%20account%3A,Service%20Accounts%20on%20Cloud%20Console.). Camel documentation has also the steps to use service account keys [Camel with Google Storage](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/google-storage-component.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation (except I would like to use google pubsub).

Inspecting relevant code suggest to me that using workload identity to authz to google service using camel is not possible ATM.

Look at [relevant code](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-3.11.1/components/camel-google/camel-google-pubsub/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/google/pubsub/GooglePubsubComponent.java) (line 170-188): it either uses the supplied key or no credentials at all.